# I am trying to extract a folder using 7-zip and AutoHotKey, but the script only opens the zipped folder in a new window

Tags: automation, scripting, autohotkey

Right-clicking on a zipped folder, pressing 7 (selects the 7-zip sub-menu), pressing e three times, and then pressing enter extracts the folder. I tried to automate this, but it just opens the zipped folder in a new window:

```
#IfWinActive, AHK_EXE Explorer.exe
^e::
blockinput on
SetKeyDelay, 5000
send {RButton}
SetKeyDelay, 5000
send 7
SetKeyDelay, 5000
send e
SetKeyDelay, 5000
send e
SetKeyDelay, 5000
send e
SetKeyDelay, 5000
send {enter}
blockinput Off
return
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `SetKeyDelay` only needs to be called once. Maybe you meant to use `Sleep`.

I got it working without `SetKeyDelay` and without needing to have the cursor over the file, because I used the "menu" key instead of a right-click. Hope this helps.

```
BlockInput Send

#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Explorer.exe
^e::
  Send {AppsKey}7eee{Enter}
  Return
```

Comment: `SendEvent` is the default send mode, and it is effected by `SetKeyDelay`. And `ahk_id` expects a hwnd, not a pid. Also `ahk_id` didn't seem to be used anywhere in his script.

Comment: I must've used the v2 docs because there `SendInput` is the default. But I have no idea how I've messed up everything else. https://youtu.be/R8vlNbk0Yww?t=14